# How to catch inline template errors in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

Suppose I have the following component:

```
@Component({
  template: '<div>{{foo.bar}}</div>'
})
class DemoComponent {
  foo = undefined;
}
```

Notice how I'm attempting to access the `bar` property of an undefined value. This throws an error similar to:

> Error in class DemoComponent - inline template:1:9 caused by: Cannot read property 'bar' of undefined

I would like to catch this error using a [custom `ErrorHandler`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ErrorHandler-class.html):

```
class LoggingErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor(private logger: Logger) {
  }

  handleError(error: any): void {
    this.logger.error(error);
  }
}
```

However, the `handleError` method is not called for template errors. My custom error handler works fine for other errors -- just not template errors. So how do I catch template errors?

Comment: What is wrong here? https://plnkr.co/edit/mvNJ61VJUlI5oITQJzaN?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for the plunker. Yeah, it looks like it's working fine there. My app is an Angular1 / Angular2 hybrid. I don't know for sure yet, but I'm guessing that that's causing issues and is the reason why the custom ErrorHandler isn't working for me.

Comment: maybe it's one of those rare times when it calls for this question having dual angular/angularjs tags

Comment: Template errors are raising during compilation phase before ErrorHandler is initialized

Answer (score 1):

You could create a template with `*ngIf="!foo.bar"`.

if it is an async request you are waiting on, you could use the async pipe with the safe operator to just wait for the value without throwing an error: `(foo | async).bar`

is there a particular reason to have a template error handler for this?